# Is there a Python function for computing a sparse non-negative factorisation of a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix-factorization

NMF finds a combination of all weights such that the weighted sum of vectors equals the desired result. However, I would like to find a non-negative factorisation where **most** weights are 0.

Is there a function for this? An ability to set the number of non-zero weights would be a bonus.

I have tested [sklearn.decomposition.NMF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html), [nimfa](https://nimfa.biolab.si/) and [Convex NMF](https://github.com/PiotrSokol/ManifoldNMF), but to no avail.

Note that the matrix itself is not sparse.

Comment: While not in python, it seems that [this Mathematica implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204430) offers a sparse result.